# Javascript countdown timer only displays once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I have a web app which after 1 hour of inactivity brings up a JQuery UI modal dialog with a 5 minute countdown timer. The first time this happens the timer works fine but if the user extends session and it comes up a second time, the timer does not display (but is still accessible in the console and still counts down)

Here is the code that runs when the popup is displayed:

```
// set countdown timer
time=5*60,r=document.getElementById('r'),tmp=time;
timer = setInterval(function(){
  var c=tmp--,m=(c/60)>>0,s=(c-m*60)+'';
  r.textContent='Time Remaining: '+m+':'+(s.length>1?'':'0')+s  
  tmp!=0||(tmp=time);
},1000);
```

Any ideas why it is not being displayed the second time?

The markup for this part of the app is very simple. I am creating the modal in Javascript like this:

```
var modal = "<div id='modal_pop'><p>"+opts.dialogText+"</p><br><br><div id='r'></div></div>";
```

And then each time the inactivity period is reached I am displaying it with the following code:

```
my_dialog = $(modal).dialog({
      buttons: buttonsOpts,
      modal: true,
      title: opts.dialogTitle
    });
```

Immediately after this I set up the timer using the first piece of code I submitted. Thanks for your help

Comment: need your html. can you make a JSFiddle?

Comment: Obviously the counter works It is the dialog that fails so that is the more important code to show. My guess is you have more than one object with ID="r" after the second click

Comment: You are applying the .dialog plugin twice (or even more). That is you have created the var modal once and every time the user has inactivity rather than showing the dialog you are applying the plugin and trying to show the modal, which works first time as its the first time the plugin is applied and not work on consecutive times is due to you are applying plugin on an element which already has the plugin.

Comment: Thanks this was a very helpful comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reuse the previously created modal dialog after the first time and call its [open](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-open) method. Here's an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var opts = {
    dialogText: 'Modal Dialog',
    dialogTitle: 'Title'
  };
  
  var modal = "<div><p>"+opts.dialogText+"</p><br><br><div class='remaining'></div></div>";
  var dialog;
  var interval;
  
  var secsToRemainingTime = function secsToRemainingTime(secs) {
      var mm = ('0'+~~(secs / 60)).slice(-2);
      var ss = ('0'+(secs % 60)).slice(-2);
      return mm + ':' + ss;
  };
  
  var showDialog = function showDialog() {
    var time = 5 * 60;
    
    dialog = dialog || $(modal).dialog({ // reuse the previously created dialog or create one for the first time
      title: opts.dialogTitle,
      modal: true,
      autoOpen: false,
      close: function(event, ui) {
        if (interval) {
          clearInterval(interval);
          interval = undefined;
        }
      }
    });
    
    dialog.dialog('open'); // http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-open
    
    var remainingDiv = dialog.children('.remaining');
    remainingDiv.html(secsToRemainingTime(time));
    
    interval = setInterval(function () {
      if (time == 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = undefined;
        // TODO: do something
        return;
      }
      remainingDiv.html(secsToRemainingTime(--time));
    }, 1000);
  }
  
  $('#show-dialog').click(showDialog);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<button id="show-dialog">Show Dialog</button>
```

Comment: Had already worked it out based on a previous comment but this was an extremely helpful and well-thought out answer. Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me :)